# Who pays gas when a contract function that creates/calls another contract is called?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, gas

If I call a function of Contract1, that creates/calls another Contract2.
Who pays the gas used to call Contract2 ?

I think it's Contract1 - the second `msg.sender`. In that case, how can I make the original `msg.sender`pay?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Gas and value in a transaction are entirely separate. When you send `x` ETH to an address, whether from an account or a contract, the recipient's balance is guaranteed to go up by `x`, regardless of how much gas was used (as long as there are no exceptions).

Additionally, gas is always paid by the original sender (`tx.origin` in Solidity), not by any intermediate contracts. The gas used in a transaction is always subtracted from the balance of the sendimg account, not of a contract.

**tl;dr: you don't need to do anything, just send enough gas in the transaction**

Comment: To highlight an exception for "recipient's balance is guaranteed to go up", is if the recipient is a [contract that rejects Ether](http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1477/42)

Comment: I thought that was covered in the "(as long as there are no exceptions)", but I guess I should be clearer

Comment: Yes you covered it, just wanted to highlight the fallback case