# How does a Solidity fallback function work with the raw CALL opcode of the EVM?

Tags: solidity, evm, fallback-function

Since a [fallback function is a Solidity feature](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1477/how-does-rejecting-ether-work-on-contracts-fallback-functions), how does it work if the EVM opcode `CALL` is used?

If `msg.data` is empty, how can Solidity run the fallback function?  Shouldn't the EVM just transfer the Ether, since there's no function invocation involved?

In Solidity, does syntax like `contractAddress.call.value(amountWei)()` invoke a raw `CALL` opcode, or does Solidity still do something additional?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any message sent to a contract, even if it is empty or just an ether transfer will invoke the code of the contract. The fallback function is run if the data sent does not start with a known function identifier (e.g. if a non-existent function is called or if the message data is empty as is the case for a simple ether transfer).

So if a contract has a fallback function, there is no way to prevent it being called (except by calling an actually existing function or not sending enough gas but no ether).

In Solidity, both `.call` and `.send` compile to the `CALL` opcode, just their expected arguments are different.

Comment: Accepted the answer but I think the key question is why this: "Any message sent to a contract, even if it is empty or just an ether transfer will invoke the code of the contract."  http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1585/why-does-an-empty-message-still-invoke-the-code-of-the-contract

Comment: To complete the answer: Solidity's ".transfer" also compiles to CALL. Both transfer() and send() differ from call() in that they set up a gas stipend of 2300 by default. With call(), the default is to use all remaining gas.