# What does msg.sender.call() do in Solidity?

Tags: solidity, security, fallback-function, reentrant-attacks

Hi was going through solidity documentation. There was some code that I was not able to understand, even after researching a lot I was not able to find some satisfactory output. The code is as under:

```
contract Mutex {
  bool locked;
modifier noReentrancy() {
    require(!locked);
    locked = true;
    _;
    locked = false;
}

/// This function is protected by a mutex, which means that
/// reentrant calls from within `msg.sender.call` cannot call `f` again.
/// The `return 7` statement assigns 7 to the return value but still
/// executes the statement `locked = false` in the modifier.
  function f() public noReentrancy returns (uint) {
    require(msg.sender.call());
   return 7;
  }
}
```

What `msg.sender.call()` does? is it calling `f()` again? If yes then how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It calls the anonymous fallback function on `msg.sender`.

In a typical reentrancy attack, it would be something like a `withdraw` function doing `msg.sender.call.value(1 ether)()`. The caller (a smart contract), would then call the function again, hence the "reentrancy" attack. In this snippet, the `call` doesn't seem to be doing anything useful, but it's just there to show that the `locked` variables guards against reentrancy.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74418/discussion-on-answer-by-smarx-what-does-msg-sender-call-do-in-solidity).

Answer (score 6):

`msg.sender.call()` calls the [fallback-function](/questions/tagged/fallback-function) on `msg.sender`.

Here is an example that is extended with a `canBeAttacked` function.

```
contract Mutex {
  bool locked;
modifier noReentrancy() {
    require(!locked);
    locked = true;
    _;
    locked = false;
}

  function canBeAttacked() public returns (uint) {
    require(msg.sender.call.value(1 ether)());
   return 7;
  }

/// This function is protected by a mutex
  function f() public noReentrancy returns (uint) {
    require(msg.sender.call());
   return 7;
  }
}
```

2 things to be aware of from above code.

1. An attacker can create a contract that has a fallback

of:

```
// attacker fallback
function() {
  Mutex(msg.sender).canBeAttacked();
}
```

The contract can have another function that calls `canBeAttacked()`, and this will keep reentering `canBeAttacked()` and send the attacker 1 ether each time.  (The fallback needs more code to avoid an infinite loop and running out of gas.)  This is an example of a reentrant attack.

Now imagine an attacker contract that has a fallback of:

```
// attacker fallback
function() {
  Mutex(msg.sender).f();
}
```

2. When attacker calls `f()`, the attacker fallback will fail because `locked` is `true`, so `require(!locked)` will generate an exception and revert the entire transaction.

Also note that `noReentrancy` prevents an attacker calling `f()` and in the attacker's fallback, calling `canBeAttacked`.  (But they can attack as #1 above.)

Comment: You didn't explain *why* anyone would want to call the sender's fallback function in the first place. What purpose does this serve?

Comment: @LukeHutchison You're right that in almost all cases one doesn't want to call the fallback function. You might be asking a similar thing I wondered about why sending ether to a contract, always invokes the fallback function? https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/how-does-a-solidity-fallback-function-work-with-the-raw-call-opcode-of-the-evm