# How do I send funds from a contract to an account using bytecode?

Tags: evm, bytecode, opcode, create

The instruction CREATE will send funds to a new account. Is there another instruction for sending funds to an account that already exists? Or I just have to use CREATE as if the account doesn't exist?

Answer (score 0):

The `CALL` opcode is the one to use for sending funds.

Yes, it is unusual that there is no opcode for just sending funds:

- [How does a Solidity fallback function work with the raw CALL opcode of the EVM?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1505/how-does-a-solidity-fallback-function-work-with-the-raw-call-opcode-of-the-evm)
- [Why does an empty message still invoke the code of the contract?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1585/why-does-an-empty-message-still-invoke-the-code-of-the-contract)