# Who pays for the gas when i send a transaction containing a signed transaction of another user

Tags: gas, raw-transaction, ethereumjs-tx

I would love it if there was a way for me to pay the gas costs for a signed transaction I receive and then relay to a node. 
So I am the submitting the transaction, but its data contains a signed raw transaction (ethereumjs-tx) of a different user.

Comment: looking at https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1452/who-pays-gas-when-a-contract-function-that-creates-calls-another-contract-is-cal?rq=1,
I suspect that `tx.origin` will be the one paying the gas :(

Comment: Why would you want to pay for another one's transaction anyway? But if you really want to do this, you can just send `gasLimit * gasPrice` to `tx.origin`.

Comment: if i do this in the smart contract though, the `tx.origin` address would need some ether to call the fct in the first place, right? I was hoping to work around any distribution scheme

Comment: Exactly. This issue is already being discussed here: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/144/can-contracts-pay-the-gas-instead-of-the-message-sender